# How LinqToSql Generates output result of stored procedures

Tags: .net, linq, stored-procedures, linq-to-sql

for example you have a stored procedure with title : **`sp_test`**
when you drag into **LinqToSql**, it generates **`sp_testResult`** class with stored procedure output columns as its properties.

I want to know how **LinqToSql** distinguish output result of stored procedure?

Comment: It run a query on SQL server that will give you all the info you need.

Comment: are you sure you get all infos you need!? there is no any info about output column names of `stored procedure`in sql server. You can use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` to get them but it only gives information about `tables` and `user defined functions`only.

Comment: Ah, I get what you saying. The way it works via .NET is using `CommandBehavior.SchemaOnly` when executing the SP via a `SqlCommand`. The empty result set has enough info to describe the output columns and types.

Comment: thanks! could you please explain it with an example as `ANSWER`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what happens in `SqlCommandBuilder.GetSchemaTable(...)` which is sadly `protected`.

```
SqlCommand command; // setup as SP

using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(
             CommandBehavior.KeyInfo | CommandBehavior.SchemaOnly))
{
  return reader.GetSchemaTable();
}
```

The resultant `DataTable` will contain the output schema.

If I remember correctly, you do not have to pass parameters for this work.